# App. works correctly using the Emulator and crashes on the SmartPhone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have astrange problem:

when I run my App. using the emulator it works. But when I tried to test it on the

SmartPhone, it crashes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a fairly standard Android dev experience. :) Examine the stack trace in logcat... it'll tell you exactly where the crash happened.

Comment: Does it crash predictably? Phones and the emulator *are not* exactly the same.

Comment: May be your code has been developed on a different version than the version on your smartphone....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you are compiling your application for a version which is supported by your phone (e.g. Android 2.1).
- Makes sure your application is correctly signed with a debug key (this is done for you in Eclipse).
- Make sure you are using libraries which are supported by your phone (e.g. if using OpenGL, make sure you have the correct version on your phone (see glbenchmark.com).

If you've checked and double checked these things, then look in the Logcat output (Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> DDMS) and see if there are any errors which can guide you to a solution.

Comment: solved..actually it was about the Application version and also because I'm working with SQLite. and the table installed on the emulator contains 88 records and the same table instaled on the device contains 45 and i tried to access the record number 87...that's why it works on the emulator but not the handset.